# Setting up 6 monitors, 2 graphics cards

Tags: linux, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, fedora

I am running Fedora 24. I have an AMD card and a NVIDIA card. Both show up in lspci | grep VGA. I've run things using the NVIDIA card (it's a gpu).

However, I'd like to use the GPU to drive 4 more monitors. I am currently driving 2 monitors with the AMD card.

I have an HDMI splitter that I want to use with the NVIDIA card. It's a GTX 1080 TI, and should support 4 cards.

I simply have no idea where to go from here... Can post xorg.conf if that helps. I can't tell if the HDMI splitter is working or not, but know that the extra 4 monitors, despite being plugged in, aren't seeing any input.

Let me know what information is needed to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: A splitter (most are garbage anyway) will only clone. HDMI supports *one* display per port.

Comment: `xrandr` will tell you which output of the GTX 1080 is active and connected to a monitor, and you can also configure the outputs. The monitors must be connected to different connectors on the GTX 1080 if you want to have different images.

Answer (score 1):

How many output ports does the 1080 have - that many maximum monitors you can use on the card.

If you want more, you can only use splitters and clone them.

And I said maximum for the following reason: just because you see three or more ports on your discrete graphics card doesn’t necessarily mean you can use all of them at the same time. For example, many older nV cards are unable to run more than two monitors on a single card, even if they have more than two ports. The best way to find out the exact model of you card and check its specs to see the maximum supported simultaneous outputs.